# Mount Davfs Cannot evaluate path of mount point

Tags: linux, debian, mount, path, webdav

I'm trying to mount a webdav on my debian distribution, but I have an error when I try to do so.

The error is :

```
~# mount /mnt/dav 
>/sbin/mount.davfs: can't evaluate path of mount point (null)
```

Last line of the fstab file (/etc/fstab) :

```
https://website.fr/remote.php/dav/files/jeffez/ /mnt/dav davfs _netdev,auto,user,uid=jeffez,gid=jeffez 0 0
```

Last lines of the davfs2 secret file (I changed the password)

```
# personal webdav, nextcloud application password
/mnt/dav jeffez Pg9z8-XFGbX-iug6R-k90D5-gK8kL
# older versions used URL, it is equivalent for compatibility reasons
#https://nextcloud.example.com/remote.php/webdav/ milosz mypassword
```

I used [this tutorial](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/09/04/how-to-mount-webdav-share/).

I'm connected with the administrator account.

Comment: To avoid requests for further clarification, you might include the steps from the tutorial that you followed.

Answer (score 4):

one reason for this error is that you did not create the directory before mounting:

`mkdir /mnt/dav`

Comment: We'll have to take them at their word that they followed [the tutorial](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/09/04/how-to-mount-webdav-share/) they linked to, and indeed ran the `mkdir`.

Comment: I encountered the same error, and I actually forgot to create the folder ...